# Linkedin API Company Updates not returning 50 recents updates

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am trying to fetch companies updates with this API
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_updates

I use Node.js with linkedin-js package module wrapper.
I found that I only got 5 posts from this company (id=3487133). But it shown in page, that it got more than 5 updates. How can I get all its posts updates ? Thanks.

Here is my code

```
var linkedin_client = require('linkedin-js')(appid, appsecret, url_callback)


var cid = 3487133;
var param = {
  token: {
    oauth_token_secret: <token_secret>,
    oauth_token: <token>
  },
  count: 50
}

//post
linkedin_client.apiCall('GET', '/companies/' + cid + '/updates', param, function(error, result) {
  console.log(result)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

From https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_updates you can find that

> Only the most recent 50 updates for events of type status-update will
>   be returned.  For all other event types, the request will return all
>   the updates within the past 20 days, or 250 total updates - whichever
>   comes first.

Using Linkedin console (https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/3487133/updates) fo getting the updates for your company, its giving the same 5 posts. Rest of the posts in your page are 20 days + older.

Comment: but i want to fetch all 50 posts at max. Why it won't fetched ?
So it just return posts 20 days back ?

Comment: Linkedin API won't provide posts which are 20 days older. You'll only get newer posts till 20 days everytime you query.